# can't figure out an error in this one-liner. php + ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

```
if (!exec($ffmpegDo)) { $error[] = ERROR_EXEC_FFMPEGDO; }
```

You see, it's simple. If exec is executed, fine, else, return error.

The problem, the exec is getting executed here, but I also have the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should read the [function description](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). It doesn't return a Boolean. It returns the last line of the output.

What is `$ffmpegDo` and what does it output?

Maybe you should supply the `&$return_var` parameter. And check the return code. Ex.:

```
exec($ffmpegDo, $output, $return_var)
if ($return_var) { $error[] = ERROR_EXEC_FFMPEGDO; }
```

Comment: php makes me chuckle every once in a while. OPs (not unreasonable) code does quite the opposite of its intention.

Comment: Tricky isn't the word I'd use.  :-)

Comment: Thanks Alin. A little function did the trick. `function Xexec($var) {
  exec($var, $output, $result);
  return $result;
 }`

Answer (score 1):

exec() returns the output of the command, not the return value.  You probably want to do something like this instead:

```
exec($ffmpegDo, $output, $return_val);
if ($return_val) { $error[] = ERROR_EXEC_FFMPEGDO; }
```

Comment: You are not entirely correct. It returns the _last line_ of the output, not the whole output.